# XMLHTTP Request not sending data across to PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using xmlhttp request to send data to my php file and then use it to get data out of a database and then show that response back at my original page. Following is the code:

```js
<script>

 function func2(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("replaceContent").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("replaceContent").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","projectdata.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="replaceContent">
                     This should be replaced.
                        <button onclick="func2(10)"> Click ME </button>
                    </div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

and the following is the projectData.php:

```html
<?php
 include 'connEst.php';
 // get the q parameter from URL
 $q = $_GET['id'];
 echo $q;
 $sql="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ID = '".$q."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 
 echo "<table>
 <tr>
 <th> $q </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Project Name</th>
 <th>Project Location</th>
 <th>Project Value</th>
 <th>Client Name</th>
 <th>Work Done in Project</th>
 <th>Project Summary</th>
 <th>Start Date</th>
 <th>End Date</th>
 </tr>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['p_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['p_loc'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['p_val'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['p_wdone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['p_summary'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['start_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['end_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I am running it on my mac using an apache server installation. I am testing this in Chrome.
The $q variable I have setup is returning a blank value when I run the file.

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ajax function sends a parameter "q" not "id" and the PHP looks for `$_GET['id']`

In projectData.php, change the existing to:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

Or change your javascript to:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","projectdata.php?id="+str,true);
```